# eBay GetOrders Unpaid Orders

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to pull a list of orders from eBay where the paid date is null. Here is my current query:

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getorders.html

Can eBay return orders that are unpaid? Do I need to add a parameter?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <eBayAuthToken>XX</eBayAuthToken>
      </RequesterCredentials>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
         <MessageID>XX</MessageID>
         <Version>779</Version>
         <CreateTimeFrom>2015-08-05T00:00:00</CreateTimeFrom>
         <CreateTimeTo>2015-08-05T23:59:00</CreateTimeTo>
         <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
         <OrderStatus>All</OrderStatus>
         <Pagination>
            <EntriesPerPage>50</EntriesPerPage>
            <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
         </Pagination>
      </GetOrdersRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: I think if you pass value "Active" for OrderStatusCodeType field then it might returns orders with payment pending. as it says on this page http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/types/OrderStatusCodeType.html This value indicates that the cart is active. The 'Active' state is the only order state in which order line items can still be added, removed, or updated in the cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the GetOrders request, but you can certainly get a list of Crimothy's who have not paid using the GetMyeBaySelling API and setting 'AwaitingPayment' as the OrderStatusFilter.

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyeBaySelling.html

This simple request should give you what you're after:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
<eBayAuthToken>... </eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<SoldList>
<Include>true</Include>
<Pagination><EntriesPerPage>100</EntriesPerPage>
<PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
</Pagination>
<OrderStatusFilter>AwaitingPayment</OrderStatusFilter>
</SoldList><DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
<Version>935</Version>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and pass in DetailLevel just before you close out `</GetOrdersRequest>`

```
<DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
```